# What tactic should I use to avoid stucking in endless loop, in Coq?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic, coqide

I cannot solve a Coq Theorem where I should use denotational semantics. If I go forward from this point I am always stucking in an endless loop.

What tactic should be used in this case? Where did I go wrong with this one? Should I start differently?

```
From Coq Require Import Strings.String
                        Arith.PeanoNat
                        Arith.Plus.

Definition Ident : Type := string.

Inductive AExp : Type :=
| ALit (n : nat)
| AVar (s : Ident)
| APlus (a1 a2 : AExp)
| ADup (n : AExp)
.

Definition State := Ident -> nat.

Definition empty : State := fun x => 0.

Definition aState : State := 
fun x =>
  match x with
  | "X"%string => 1
  | "Y"%string => 2
  | "Z"%string => 42
  | _ => 0
  end
.

Definition X:Ident := "X"%string.
Definition Y:Ident := "Y"%string.
Definition Z:Ident := "Z"%string.

Fixpoint val (a : AExp) (s : State) : nat :=
match a with
| ALit n => n
| AVar x => s x
| APlus a1 a2 => val a1 s + val a2 s
| ADup a => val a s + val a s
end.

Fixpoint aqb (a1 a2 : AExp) : bool :=
match a1, a2 with
| ALit n, ALit m => Nat.eqb n m
| AVar s, AVar x => String.eqb s x
| APlus a1 a2, APlus a1' a2' => aqb a1 a1' && aqb a2 a2'
| ADup a1, ADup a1' => aqb a1 a1'
| _, _ => false
end.

Fixpoint optmal (a : AExp) : AExp :=
match a with
| APlus a1 a2 => 
  if aqb a1 a2
  then ADup (optmal a1)
  else APlus (optmal a1) (optmal a2)
| ADup a0 => ADup (optmal a0)
| _ => a
end.

Theorem optmald :
  forall a s, val a s = val (optmal a) s.
Proof.
intros. unfold val. induction a.
* simpl. reflexivity.
* simpl. reflexivity.
*
```

Answer (score 0):

First, instead of `unfold val`, it's better to rely on `simpl` after `induction` to simplify things, as that generally leads to goals that are easier to read.

```
Theorem optmald :
  forall a s, val a s = val (optmal a) s.
Proof.
intros. induction a; simpl.
* reflexivity.
* reflexivity.
*
```

Now the goal looks like

```
val a1 s + val a2 s =
val (if aqb a1 a2 then ADup (optmal a1) else APlus (optmal a1) (optmal a2)) s
```

When there is an `if` (or a `match`) in the goal, one often good step is to `destruct` the scrutinee:

```
destruct (aqb a1 a2) eqn:Ea.
```

Comment: Thank you! It indeed looks better, however now I always reach the following, where I am stucked again:

`n + n0 = n + n`

Do you might have any other suggestion?

Comment: In the case where `aqb a1 a2` is true, you would expect that `a1` and `a2` evaluate to the same result. That's a separate lemma you can prove.

Comment: Hi, thank you! Cannot it be proven in the same Theorem? I want to apply Ea in this case but does not let me. It should be logical. Isn't it?

`Theorem optmald :
  forall a s, val a s = val (optmal a) s.
Proof.
intros. induction a.
* simpl. reflexivity.
* simpl. reflexivity.
* simpl. destruct (aqb a1 a2) eqn:Ea.
** destruct a1.
*** simpl. destruct a2.
**** simpl in *.`


Ea : (n =? n0) = true
______________________________________(1/1)
n + n0 = n + n

Comment: No, it's subtle but `(n =? n0) = true` and `n = n0` mean different things and the fact that they are logically equivalent is a fact that needs to be proved explicitly (otherwise, one might define `Nat.eqb` so that it is not true). The version for `Nat.eqb` is in the standard library (`Search Nat.eqb.`) but you will need to prove a similar lemma for `aqb` yourself to be able to "apply `Ea`".

Comment: Hi, you are right! Those parts have been added as well, but still stucked in the loop. Please help, I just cannot figure out. I have added the next part in another answer.

Comment: `apply aqb_eq in Ea.` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

The theorem follows by induction on `a`.  However, it is useful to first prove the lemma `aeq_val` first.  It follows by induction on `a1` and considering the cases of `a2` and whether or not the branches of `a1` and `a2` are equal.  All of the `rewrite`ing can be handled automatically by `congruence` which is a tactic that can solve many goals that only require reasoning about equalities and reflexivity.

```
Lemma aeq_val : forall  a1 a2 s, aqb a1 a2 = true -> val (optmal a2) s = val (optmal a1) s.
  induction a1; destruct a2; simpl; try congruence; intros ? H.
  - apply eq_sym, EqNat.beq_nat_eq, eq_sym, H. 
  - apply eq_sym, f_equal, String.eqb_eq, H.
  - destruct (andb_prop _ _ H) as [H1 H2].
    apply aqb_eq in H1; apply aqb_eq in H2.
    destruct (aqb a2_1 a2_2) eqn:Hx;
      destruct (aqb a1_1 a1_2) eqn:Hy;
      congruence.
  - apply aqb_eq in H; congruence.
Qed.


Theorem optmald :
  forall a s, val a s = val (optmal a) s.
Proof.
  induction a; intros ?; simpl; auto.
  destruct (aqb a1 a2) eqn:H;
    rewrite IHa1, IHa2; auto;
      clear IHa1 IHa2.
  simpl; apply f_equal, aeq_val; auto.
Qed.
```